# Emacs org-mode is broken in mac os x lion terminal

Tags: emacs, terminal, org-mode

I upgraded my emacs recently to 24.2 cocoa using homebrew, and now org-mode is pretty much useless in the terminal. The problem is more irritating than it would be if it didn't work at all, which would give me a clue as to how to fix it.

When I'm editing a list (using the asterisk), and contract or expand the elements of the list (using tab), all kinds of weirdness occurs. Some list items will suddenly duplicate. Some list items will disappear completely. Items will be pushed way down the page, and then jump back up. This is all happening as I'm pushing nothing but tab.

I've uninstalled, reinstalled emacs using brew. I've done a lot of googling but can't find anyone who has had this problem with org-mode. Anyone have any ideas?

Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5
Emacs 24.2
org-version 7.8.11

Comment: Do you get the same results using Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com/?

Comment: Have you tried to create a testuser with no emacs configuration?

Comment: Does that mean running emacs with a clean .emacs file? In that case, yes, with no change. I've since given up on using org-mode in the terminal and have been using the emacs gui without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a different terminal emulator? They all have different bugs, so perhaps you've tripped over one in the default Terminal app. Try a plain xterm instead. I assume that emacs works fine when it's not in a terminal.